# Front End & Back End in MS ACCESS

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, frontend

I have a client who owns a restaurant and he asked me to make a data entry software for him. I choose ms access for it.
I created forms in ms access and tables and sort them as front end and back end.
In front end user can see forms and enter data only and in back end user can see db structure and access data in tables also.

I want to show front end to user only and restrict it to enter back end with password protection. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: You can add a database password which you must refer to in the front-end, so the security is paper thin and will only stop casual tampering by an amateur.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to put an autoexec form in the back end that opens a log-in form.  You would have to disable the shift/Enter combination (there's code out there that will do it) so the log-in form couldn't be circumnavigated.  This way anyone entering the back end separate from the front end would need to know the password.